# If $\{a_n\}$ is a bounded seq of non-neg numbers, $\alpha \in (0,1)$, then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $\{a_n\}$ is a bounded sequence of non-negative real numbers, with $\alpha \in (0,1)$, then if
$$|\{n \in \mathbb{N}: a_n \ge \frac{1}{2^n}\}| \leq 2^{n\alpha} $$

Prove that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges.

My idea is to use the ceiling function to estimate the unbounded terms as follows:

$$|\{n \in \mathbb{N}: a_n \ge \frac{1}{2^n}\}| \leq 2^{n\alpha} < 2^{\lceil n\alpha\rceil}$$

Then

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k \le \sum_{k=1}^{2^{\lceil n\alpha\rceil}}a_k + \sum_{k=2^{\lceil n\alpha\rceil + 1}}^{\infty}a_k \leq S + \sum_{k=2^{\lceil n\alpha\rceil + 1}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k} = S + \frac{2^{-2^{\lceil n\alpha\rceil + 1}}}{1 - \frac{1}{2}} < \infty$$

Where S is the partial sum of the series up to the ceiling.

Hence, the series converges.

Is my proof correct? It looks weird and did it right now at almost 1 am, so I'm not sure. Any other approaches will be interesting. Thanks.

Comment: I'm just wondering if I can say that the rest of the terms are less than $\frac{1}{2^n}$

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow.  In $\lvert\{n\in\mathbb{N}: a_n\geq\frac{1}{2^n}\}\rvert\leq 2^{n\alpha}$, where does the $n$ outside of the magnitude come from?  How is it defined?

Comment: @NickPeterson I guess is the same of the n-th term... Is from various past qualifying exams It does not say anything else.

Comment: The $n$ inside the set notation has no meaning outside of it.  As stated, this is meaningless.  And without understanding the condition given, it is awfully hard to use it to prove anything.

Comment: Your proof also uses $n$'s outside of their area of definition -- it is meaningless.  How can you justify a summation bound like $n=2^{\lceil n\alpha\rceil+1}$?

Comment: By the way, @NickPeterson I have two different exams with the same problem and it is stated as I write the problem here. Take a look at my review. I change the index.

Comment: @NickPeterson I suspect that the correct formulation of the problem should be that $\# \{ k \in \Bbb N: a_k \geq 2^{-n} \} \leq 2^{\alpha n}$, for every $n$. In this case the claim is true. Then again, I can't say for certain what it should or should not say. As currently stated, you are right that the problem does not make any sense (hence neither does the solution).

Comment: @Shalop I assumed that for the proof then it is correct?

Comment: @RichardClare No, it is still not correct. In fact the solution you wrote doesn't make much sense at all. If you want, I could post a solution (however, I would suggest that you try a bit more).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that Shalop's formulation of the problem is the correct one. You should have $|\{k\in\mathbb N: a_k\geq 2^{-n}\}|\leq 2^{\alpha n}$ for every $n$. Let $A$ be the bound of the sequence $\{a_k\}$. Then, since all the $a_k$'s are non-negative, arrange the sum in the following way:
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k=\sum\limits_{a_k\geq2^{-1}}a_k~+~\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{2^{-n}\leq a_k<2^{-n+1}}a_k~\leq 2A +\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{2^{-n}\leq a_k<2^{-n+1}}2^{-n+1}\leq2A+\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}2^{-n+1}2^{n\alpha},
$$
and this latter sum converges since $\alpha\in(0,1)$.

Comment: Thank you. Very short and simple solution.